# Why are both threads not executing simultaneously?

Tags: python, multithreading, tkinter, tcp, queue

This is my first attempt with threading and I have run into numerous hurdles already! So my code runs two threads in parallel, one which runs a function to receive data blocks from the server and puts them into a queue and the other which runs a function that removes the data blocks from the queue and performs calculations until the queue is empty.

The client code is:

```
import socket
import turtle
import queue
import threading
#import timeit
from tkinter import *

class GUI:
    entries = []
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        master.title("Collision Detection")

        self.buff_data = queue.Queue()

        self.t1 = threading.Thread(target = self.recvData)
        self.t2 = threading.Thread(target=self.calculate_threshold)
        self.entries = []

        self.host = '127.0.0.1'
        self.port = 5001
        self.s = socket.socket()
        self.s.connect((self.host, self.port))

        self.create_GUI()

    def create_GUI(self):

    
        self.input_label = Label(root, text = "Input all the gratings set straight wavelength values in nm")
        self.input_label.grid(row = 0)
    
        self.core_string = "Core "
        #entries = []
        self.label_col_inc = 0
        self.entry_col_inc = 1
        self.core_range = range(1, 5)

        for y in self.core_range:
            self.core_text = self.core_string + str(y) + '_' + '25'
            self.core_label = Label(root, text = self.core_text)
            self.entry = Entry(root)
            self.core_label.grid(row=1, column=self.label_col_inc, sticky=E)
            self.entry.grid(row=1, column=self.entry_col_inc)
            self.entries.append(self.entry)
            self.label_col_inc += 2
            self.entry_col_inc += 2
    
        self.threshold_label = Label(root, text = "Threshold in nm")
        self.entry_threshold = Entry(root)

        self.threshold_label.grid(row = 2, sticky = E)
        self.entry_threshold.grid(row = 2, column = 1)
    
        self.light_label = Label(root, text = 'Status')
        self.light_label.grid(row = 3, column = 3)

        self.canvas = Canvas(root, width = 150, height = 50)
        self.canvas.grid(row = 4, column = 3)
    
        # Green light
        self.green_light = turtle.RawTurtle(self.canvas)
        self.green_light.shape('circle')
        self.green_light.color('grey')
        self.green_light.penup()
        self.green_light.goto(0,0)

        # Red light
        self.red_light = turtle.RawTurtle(self.canvas)
        self.red_light.shape('circle')
        self.red_light.color('grey')
        self.red_light.penup()
        self.red_light.goto(40,0)
    
        self.data_button = Button(root, text = "Get data above threshold", command = self.getData)
        self.data_button.grid(row = 5, column = 0)


# function to receive TCP data blocks
    def getData(self):
        #start = timeit.default_timer()
        len_message = self.s.recv(4)
        print('len_message', len_message)
        bytes_length = int(len_message.decode('utf-8'))  # for the self-made server
        recvd_data = self.s.recv(bytes_length)
        print('data', recvd_data)
        self.buff_data.put(recvd_data)
       #stop = timeit.default_timer()
       #print('Time: ', stop - start)  gives 0.0002s
        self.t1.start()
        self.t2.start()

            
    def recvData(self):
        len_message = self.s.recv(4)
        print('len_message', len_message)
        while len_message:
            bytes_length = int(len_message.decode('utf-8'))  # for the self-made server
            recvd_data = self.s.recv(bytes_length)
            print('data', recvd_data)
            self.buff_data.put(recvd_data)
            len_message = self.s.recv(4)
            print('len_message', len_message)

        else:
            print('out of loop')

        self.s.close()


    def calculate_threshold(self):
       #start = timeit.default_timer()
        print('Calculating:')
        while not self.buff_data.empty():
            print('okay enter')
            rmv_data = self.buff_data.get()
            stringdata = rmv_data.decode('utf-8')
            rep_str = stringdata.replace(",", ".")
            splitstr = rep_str.split()
            inc = 34
            wav_threshold = []

            for y in self.entries:
                straight_wav = float(y.get())
                wav = float(splitstr[inc])
                wav_diff = wav - straight_wav
                if wav_diff < 0:
                    wav_diff = wav_diff * (-1)
                wav_threshold.append(wav_diff)
                inc += 56

            threshold = float(self.entry_threshold.get())


            for x in wav_threshold:
                if (x > threshold):
                    self.red_light.color('red')
                    self.green_light.color('grey')

                else:
                    self.red_light.color('grey')
                    self.green_light.color('green')

            #stop = timeit.default_timer()
            #print('Time: ', stop - start)  gives 0.11s




# function to write into the file
    def write_file(self,data):
        with open("Output.txt", "a") as text_file:
            text_file.write('\t'.join(data[0:]))
            text_file.write('\n')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = Tk()
    gui = GUI(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

I ran a server code to send only one data block with both threads commented and ran the start and stop variables of `getData()` and saw it takes 0.0002s to transfer one data block. Then I ran the server code to send only one data block and ran the start and stop variables of  only `calculate_threshold()` and saw it takes 0.12407s to perform the calculations.

Based on this I removed the `timeit` variables and sent around 34 data blocks (due to limitation of word limit in the body of my post, I have shown only few below) with a time delay of 0.5s after sending 10 data blocks and noticed that I get this in my console:

```
C:\Users\PycharmProjects\GUI\venv\Scripts\python.exe C:/Users/PycharmProjects/GUI/GUI_v4.py
len_message b'1685'
data b' 2020/03/02\t14:42:05\t318301\t4\t1\t25\t0\t0\t0\t0\t1513,094\t1516,156\t1519,154\t1521,969\t1525,029\t1527,813\t1530,921\t1533,869\t1536,740\t1539,943\t1542,921\t1545,879\t1548,843\t1551,849\t1554,760\t1557,943\t1560,782\t1563,931\t1566,786\t1569,751\t1572,690\t1575,535\t1578,638\t1581,755\t1584,759\t41\t39\t33\t39\t48\t44\t49\t55\t61\t58\t64\t55\t68\t74\t68\t59\t57\t74\t61\t68\t58\t64\t54\t47\t46\t2\t25\t0\t0\t0\t0\t1512,963\t1515,935\t1518,857\t1521,849\t1524,655\t1527,577\t1530,332\t1533,233\t1536,204\t1539,488\t1542,571\t1545,725\t1549,200\t1552,430\t1555,332\t1558,484\t1561,201\t1564,285\t1567,001\t1569,870\t1572,758\t1575,491\t1578,512\t1581,547\t1584,405\t48\t43\t37\t42\t57\t54\t59\t62\t67\t58\t71\t59\t77\t82\t82\t64\t71\t88\t77\t79\t72\t73\t63\t49\t50\t3\t25\t0\t0\t0\t0\t1513,394\t1516,517\t1519,536\t1522,082\t1525,428\t1527,963\t1531,288\t1534,102\t1536,659\t1539,757\t1542,707\t1545,627\t1548,389\t1551,459\t1554,406\t1557,986\t1560,667\t1564,103\t1567,036\t1570,144\t1573,189\t1575,888\t1579,185\t1582,323\t1585,338\t35\t36\t32\t37\t57\t58\t61\t64\t75\t73\t70\t62\t61\t62\t59\t51\t52\t64\t58\t62\t70\t70\t64\t54\t55\t4\t25\t0\t0\t0\t0\t1512,658\t1515,752\t1518,797\t1521,707\t1524,744\t1527,627\t1530,871\t1534,002\t1537,086\t1540,320\t1543,217\t1546,010\t1548,660\t1551,385\t1554,253\t1557,074\t1560,193\t1563,116\t1566,043\t1568,963\t1571,855\t1574,957\t1577,954\t1581,128\t1584,273\t43\t42\t39\t40\t56\t50\t56\t62\t65\t54\t59\t62\t75\t79\t73\t63\t67\t77\t73\t75\t68\t62\t54\t51\t51\t100 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN'
len_message b'1685'
data b' 2020/03/03\t14:42:05\t318302\t4\t1\t25\t0\t0\t0\t0\t1513,094\t1516,156\t1519,154\t1521,969\t1525,029\t1527,813\t1530,921\t1533,869\t1536,740\t1539,943\t1542,921\t1545,879\t1548,843\t1551,849\t1554,760\t1557,943\t1560,782\t1563,931\t1566,786\t1569,751\t1572,690\t1575,535\t1578,638\t1581,755\t1584,759\t41\t39\t33\t39\t48\t44\t49\t55\t61\t58\t64\t55\t68\t74\t68\t59\t57\t74\t61\t68\t58\t64\t54\t47\t46\t2\t25\t0\t0\t0\t0\t1512,963\t1515,935\t1518,857\t1521,849\t1524,655\t1527,577\t1530,332\t1533,233\t1536,204\t1539,488\t1542,571\t1545,725\t1549,200\t1552,430\t1555,332\t1558,484\t1561,201\t1564,285\t1567,001\t1569,870\t1572,758\t1575,491\t1578,512\t1581,547\t1584,405\t48\t43\t37\t42\t57\t54\t59\t62\t67\t58\t71\t59\t77\t82\t82\t64\t71\t88\t77\t79\t72\t73\t63\t49\t50\t3\t25\t0\t0\t0\t0\t1513,394\t1516,517\t1519,536\t1522,082\t1525,428\t1527,963\t1531,288\t1534,102\t1536,659\t1539,757\t1542,707\t1545,627\t1548,389\t1551,459\t1554,406\t1557,986\t1560,667\t1564,103\t1567,036\t1570,144\t1573,189\t1575,888\t1579,185\t1582,323\t1585,338\t35\t36\t32\t37\t57\t58\t61\t64\t75\t73\t70\t62\t61\t62\t59\t51\t52\t64\t58\t62\t70\t70\t64\t54\t55\t4\t25\t0\t0\t0\t0\t1512,658\t1515,752\t1518,797\t1521,707\t1524,744\t1527,627\t1530,871\t1534,002\t1537,086\t1540,320\t1543,217\t1546,010\t1548,660\t1551,385\t1554,253\t1557,074\t1560,193\t1563,116\t1566,043\t1568,963\t1571,855\t1574,957\t1577,954\t1581,128\t1584,273\t43\t42\t39\t40\t56\t50\t56\t62\t65\t54\t59\t62\t75\t79\t73\t63\t67\t77\t73\t75\t68\t62\t54\t51\t51\t100 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN'
len_message b'1685'
data b' 2020/03/04\t14:42:05\t318303\t4\t1\t25\t0\t0\t0\t0\t1513,094\t1516,156\t1519,154\t1521,969\t1525,029\t1527,813\t1530,921\t1533,869\t1536,740\t1539,943\t1542,921\t1545,879\t1548,843\t1551,849\t1554,760\t1557,943\t1560,782\t1563,931\t1566,786\t1569,751\t1572,690\t1575,535\t1578,638\t1581,755\t1584,759\t41\t39\t33\t39\t48\t44\t49\t55\t61\t58\t64\t55\t68\t74\t68\t59\t57\t74\t61\t68\t58\t64\t54\t47\t46\t2\t25\t0\t0\t0\t0\t1512,963\t1515,935\t1518,857\t1521,849\t1524,655\t1527,577\t1530,332\t1533,233\t1536,204\t1539,488\t1542,571\t1545,725\t1549,200\t1552,430\t1555,332\t1558,484\t1561,201\t1564,285\t1567,001\t1569,870\t1572,758\t1575,491\t1578,512\t1581,547\t1584,405\t48\t43\t37\t42\t57\t54\t59\t62\t67\t58\t71\t59\t77\t82\t82\t64\t71\t88\t77\t79\t72\t73\t63\t49\t50\t3\t25\t0\t0\t0\t0\t1513,394\t1516,517\t1519,536\t1522,082\t1525,428\t1527,963\t1531,288\t1534,102\t1536,659\t1539,757\t1542,707\t1545,627\t1548,389\t1551,459\t1554,406\t1557,986\t1560,667\t1564,103\t1567,036\t1570,144\t1573,189\t1575,888\t1579,185\t1582,323\t1585,338\t35\t36\t32\t37\t57\t58\t61\t64\t75\t73\t70\t62\t61\t62\t59\t51\t52\t64\t58\t62\t70\t70\t64\t54\t55\t4\t25\t0\t0\t0\t0\t1512,658\t1515,752\t1518,797\t1521,707\t1524,744\t1527,627\t1530,871\t1534,002\t1537,086\t1540,320\t1543,217\t1546,010\t1548,660\t1551,385\t1554,253\t1557,074\t1560,193\t1563,116\t1566,043\t1568,963\t1571,855\t1574,957\t1577,954\t1581,128\t1584,273\t43\t42\t39\t40\t56\t50\t56\t62\t65\t54\t59\t62\t75\t79\t73\t63\t67\t77\t73\t75\t68\t62\t54\t51\t51\t100 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN'Calculating:

okay enterlen_message b'1685'

data b' 2020/03/05\t14:42:05\t318411\t4\t1\t25\t0\t0\t0\t0\t1513,094\t1516,156\t1519,154\t1521,969\t1525,029\t1527,813\t1530,921\t1533,869\t1536,740\t1539,943\t1542,921\t1545,879\t1548,843\t1551,849\t1554,760\t1557,943\t1560,782\t1563,931\t1566,786\t1569,751\t1572,690\t1575,535\t1578,638\t1581,755\t1584,759\t41\t39\t33\t39\t48\t44\t49\t55\t61\t58\t64\t55\t68\t74\t68\t59\t57\t74\t61\t68\t58\t64\t54\t47\t46\t2\t25\t0\t0\t0\t0\t1512,963\t1515,935\t1518,857\t1521,849\t1524,655\t1527,577\t1530,332\t1533,233\t1536,204\t1539,488\t1542,571\t1545,725\t1549,200\t1552,430\t1555,332\t1558,484\t1561,201\t1564,285\t1567,001\t1569,870\t1572,758\t1575,491\t1578,512\t1581,547\t1584,405\t48\t43\t37\t42\t57\t54\t59\t62\t67\t58\t71\t59\t77\t82\t82\t64\t71\t88\t77\t79\t72\t73\t63\t49\t50\t3\t25\t0\t0\t0\t0\t1513,394\t1516,517\t1519,536\t1522,082\t1525,428\t1527,963\t1531,288\t1534,102\t1536,659\t1539,757\t1542,707\t1545,627\t1548,389\t1551,459\t1554,406\t1557,986\t1560,667\t1564,103\t1567,036\t1570,144\t1573,189\t1575,888\t1579,185\t1582,323\t1585,338\t35\t36\t32\t37\t57\t58\t61\t64\t75\t73\t70\t62\t61\t62\t59\t51\t52\t64\t58\t62\t70\t70\t64\t54\t55\t4\t25\t0\t0\t0\t0\t1512,658\t1515,752\t1518,797\t1521,707\t1524,744\t1527,627\t1530,871\t1534,002\t1537,086\t1540,320\t1543,217\t1546,010\t1548,660\t1551,385\t1554,253\t1557,074\t1560,193\t1563,116\t1566,043\t1568,963\t1571,855\t1574,957\t1577,954\t1581,128\t1584,273\t43\t42\t39\t40\t56\t50\t56\t62\t65\t54\t59\t62\t75\t79\t73\t63\t67\t77\t73\t75\t68\t62\t54\t51\t51\t100 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN'
len_message b'1685'
data b' 2020/03/06\t14:42:05\t318411\t4\t1\t25\t0\t0\t0\t0\t1513,094\t1516,156\t1519,154\t1521,969\t1525,029\t1527,813\t1530,921\t1533,869\t1536,740\t1539,943\t1542,921\t1545,879\t1548,843\t1551,849\t1554,760\t1557,943\t1560,782\t1563,931\t1566,786\t1569,751\t1572,690\t1575,535\t1578,638\t1581,755\t1584,759\t41\t39\t33\t39\t48\t44\t49\t55\t61\t58\t64\t55\t68\t74\t68\t59\t57\t74\t61\t68\t58\t64\t54\t47\t46\t2\t25\t0\t0\t0\t0\t1512,963\t1515,935\t1518,857\t1521,849\t1524,655\t1527,577\t1530,332\t1533,233\t1536,204\t1539,488\t1542,571\t1545,725\t1549,200\t1552,430\t1555,332\t1558,484\t1561,201\t1564,285\t1567,001\t1569,870\t1572,758\t1575,491\t1578,512\t1581,547\t1584,405\t48\t43\t37\t42\t57\t54\t59\t62\t67\t58\t71\t59\t77\t82\t82\t64\t71\t88\t77\t79\t72\t73\t63\t49\t50\t3\t25\t0\t0\t0\t0\t1513,394\t1516,517\t1519,536\t1522,082\t1525,428\t1527,963\t1531,288\t1534,102\t1536,659\t1539,757\t1542,707\t1545,627\t1548,389\t1551,459\t1554,406\t1557,986\t1560,667\t1564,103\t1567,036\t1570,144\t1573,189\t1575,888\t1579,185\t1582,323\t1585,338\t35\t36\t32\t37\t57\t58\t61\t64\t75\t73\t70\t62\t61\t62\t59\t51\t52\t64\t58\t62\t70\t70\t64\t54\t55\t4\t25\t0\t0\t0\t0\t1512,658\t1515,752\t1518,797\t1521,707\t1524,744\t1527,627\t1530,871\t1534,002\t1537,086\t1540,320\t1543,217\t1546,010\t1548,660\t1551,385\t1554,253\t1557,074\t1560,193\t1563,116\t1566,043\t1568,963\t1571,855\t1574,957\t1577,954\t1581,128\t1584,273\t43\t42\t39\t40\t56\t50\t56\t62\t65\t54\t59\t62\t75\t79\t73\t63\t67\t77\t73\t75\t68\t62\t54\t51\t51\t100 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN'
len_message b'1685'
data b' 2020/03/07\t14:42:05\t318411\t4\t1\t25\t0\t0\t0\t0\t1513,094\t1516,156\t1519,154\t1521,969\t1525,029\t1527,813\t1530,921\t1533,869\t1536,740\t1539,943\t1542,921\t1545,879\t1548,843\t1551,849\t1554,760\t1557,943\t1560,782\t1563,931\t1566,786\t1569,751\t1572,690\t1575,535\t1578,638\t1581,755\t1584,759\t41\t39\t33\t39\t48\t44\t49\t55\t61\t58\t64\t55\t68\t74\t68\t59\t57\t74\t61\t68\t58\t64\t54\t47\t46\t2\t25\t0\t0\t0\t0\t1512,963\t1515,935\t1518,857\t1521,849\t1524,655\t1527,577\t1530,332\t1533,233\t1536,204\t1539,488\t1542,571\t1545,725\t1549,200\t1552,430\t1555,332\t1558,484\t1561,201\t1564,285\t1567,001\t1569,870\t1572,758\t1575,491\t1578,512\t1581,547\t1584,405\t48\t43\t37\t42\t57\t54\t59\t62\t67\t58\t71\t59\t77\t82\t82\t64\t71\t88\t77\t79\t72\t73\t63\t49\t50\t3\t25\t0\t0\t0\t0\t1513,394\t1516,517\t1519,536\t1522,082\t1525,428\t1527,963\t1531,288\t1534,102\t1536,659\t1539,757\t1542,707\t1545,627\t1548,389\t1551,459\t1554,406\t1557,986\t1560,667\t1564,103\t1567,036\t1570,144\t1573,189\t1575,888\t1579,185\t1582,323\t1585,338\t35\t36\t32\t37\t57\t58\t61\t64\t75\t73\t70\t62\t61\t62\t59\t51\t52\t64\t58\t62\t70\t70\t64\t54\t55\t4\t25\t0\t0\t0\t0\t1512,658\t1515,752\t1518,797\t1521,707\t1524,744\t1527,627\t1530,871\t1534,002\t1537,086\t1540,320\t1543,217\t1546,010\t1548,660\t1551,385\t1554,253\t1557,074\t1560,193\t1563,116\t1566,043\t1568,963\t1571,855\t1574,957\t1577,954\t1581,128\t1584,273\t43\t42\t39\t40\t56\t50\t56\t62\t65\t54\t59\t62\t75\t79\t73\t63\t67\t77\t73\t75\t68\t62\t54\t51\t51\t100 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN'
len_message b'1685'
data b' 2020/03/08\t14:42:05\t318411\t4\t1\t25\t0\t0\t0\t0\t1513,094\t1516,156\t1519,154\t1521,969\t1525,029\t1527,813\t1530,921\t1533,869\t1536,740\t1539,943\t1542,921\t1545,879\t1548,843\t1551,849\t1554,760\t1557,943\t1560,782\t1563,931\t1566,786\t1569,751\t1572,690\t1575,535\t1578,638\t1581,755\t1584,759\t41\t39\t33\t39\t48\t44\t49\t55\t61\t58\t64\t55\t68\t74\t68\t59\t57\t74\t61\t68\t58\t64\t54\t47\t46\t2\t25\t0\t0\t0\t0\t1512,963\t1515,935\t1518,857\t1521,849\t1524,655\t1527,577\t1530,332\t1533,233\t1536,204\t1539,488\t1542,571\t1545,725\t1549,200\t1552,430\t1555,332\t1558,484\t1561,201\t1564,285\t1567,001\t1569,870\t1572,758\t1575,491\t1578,512\t1581,547\t1584,405\t48\t43\t37\t42\t57\t54\t59\t62\t67\t58\t71\t59\t77\t82\t82\t64\t71\t88\t77\t79\t72\t73\t63\t49\t50\t3\t25\t0\t0\t0\t0\t1513,394\t1516,517\t1519,536\t1522,082\t1525,428\t1527,963\t1531,288\t1534,102\t1536,659\t1539,757\t1542,707\t1545,627\t1548,389\t1551,459\t1554,406\t1557,986\t1560,667\t1564,103\t1567,036\t1570,144\t1573,189\t1575,888\t1579,185\t1582,323\t1585,338\t35\t36\t32\t37\t57\t58\t61\t64\t75\t73\t70\t62\t61\t62\t59\t51\t52\t64\t58\t62\t70\t70\t64\t54\t55\t4\t25\t0\t0\t0\t0\t1512,658\t1515,752\t1518,797\t1521,707\t1524,744\t1527,627\t1530,871\t1534,002\t1537,086\t1540,320\t1543,217\t1546,010\t1548,660\t1551,385\t1554,253\t1557,074\t1560,193\t1563,116\t1566,043\t1568,963\t1571,855\t1574,957\t1577,954\t1581,128\t1584,273\t43\t42\t39\t40\t56\t50\t56\t62\t65\t54\t59\t62\t75\t79\t73\t63\t67\t77\t73\t75\t68\t62\t54\t51\t51\t100 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN'
len_message b'1685'
data b' 2020/03/09\t14:42:05\t318411\t4\t1\t25\t0\t0\t0\t0\t1513,094\t1516,156\t1519,154\t1521,969\t1525,029\t1527,813\t1530,921\t1533,869\t1536,740\t1539,943\t1542,921\t1545,879\t1548,843\t1551,849\t1554,760\t1557,943\t1560,782\t1563,931\t1566,786\t1569,751\t1572,690\t1575,535\t1578,638\t1581,755\t1584,759\t41\t39\t33\t39\t48\t44\t49\t55\t61\t58\t64\t55\t68\t74\t68\t59\t57\t74\t61\t68\t58\t64\t54\t47\t46\t2\t25\t0\t0\t0\t0\t1512,963\t1515,935\t1518,857\t1521,849\t1524,655\t1527,577\t1530,332\t1533,233\t1536,204\t1539,488\t1542,571\t1545,725\t1549,200\t1552,430\t1555,332\t1558,484\t1561,201\t1564,285\t1567,001\t1569,870\t1572,758\t1575,491\t1578,512\t1581,547\t1584,405\t48\t43\t37\t42\t57\t54\t59\t62\t67\t58\t71\t59\t77\t82\t82\t64\t71\t88\t77\t79\t72\t73\t63\t49\t50\t3\t25\t0\t0\t0\t0\t1513,394\t1516,517\t1519,536\t1522,082\t1525,428\t1527,963\t1531,288\t1534,102\t1536,659\t1539,757\t1542,707\t1545,627\t1548,389\t1551,459\t1554,406\t1557,986\t1560,667\t1564,103\t1567,036\t1570,144\t1573,189\t1575,888\t1579,185\t1582,323\t1585,338\t35\t36\t32\t37\t57\t58\t61\t64\t75\t73\t70\t62\t61\t62\t59\t51\t52\t64\t58\t62\t70\t70\t64\t54\t55\t4\t25\t0\t0\t0\t0\t1512,658\t1515,752\t1518,797\t1521,707\t1524,744\t1527,627\t1530,871\t1534,002\t1537,086\t1540,320\t1543,217\t1546,010\t1548,660\t1551,385\t1554,253\t1557,074\t1560,193\t1563,116\t1566,043\t1568,963\t1571,855\t1574,957\t1577,954\t1581,128\t1584,273\t43\t42\t39\t40\t56\t50\t56\t62\t65\t54\t59\t62\t75\t79\t73\t63\t67\t77\t73\t75\t68\t62\t54\t51\t51\t100 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN'
len_message b'1685'
data b' 2020/03/10\t14:42:05\t318411\t4\t1\t25\t0\t0\t0\t0\t1513,094\t1516,156\t1519,154\t1521,969\t1525,029\t1527,813\t1530,921\t1533,869\t1536,740\t1539,943\t1542,921\t1545,879\t1548,843\t1551,849\t1554,760\t1557,943\t1560,782\t1563,931\t1566,786\t1569,751\t1572,690\t1575,535\t1578,638\t1581,755\t1584,759\t41\t39\t33\t39\t48\t44\t49\t55\t61\t58\t64\t55\t68\t74\t68\t59\t57\t74\t61\t68\t58\t64\t54\t47\t46\t2\t25\t0\t0\t0\t0\t1512,963\t1515,935\t1518,857\t1521,849\t1524,655\t1527,577\t1530,332\t1533,233\t1536,204\t1539,488\t1542,571\t1545,725\t1549,200\t1552,430\t1555,332\t1558,484\t1561,201\t1564,285\t1567,001\t1569,870\t1572,758\t1575,491\t1578,512\t1581,547\t1584,405\t48\t43\t37\t42\t57\t54\t59\t62\t67\t58\t71\t59\t77\t82\t82\t64\t71\t88\t77\t79\t72\t73\t63\t49\t50\t3\t25\t0\t0\t0\t0\t1513,394\t1516,517\t1519,536\t1522,082\t1525,428\t1527,963\t1531,288\t1534,102\t1536,659\t1539,757\t1542,707\t1545,627\t1548,389\t1551,459\t1554,406\t1557,986\t1560,667\t1564,103\t1567,036\t1570,144\t1573,189\t1575,888\t1579,185\t1582,323\t1585,338\t35\t36\t32\t37\t57\t58\t61\t64\t75\t73\t70\t62\t61\t62\t59\t51\t52\t64\t58\t62\t70\t70\t64\t54\t55\t4\t25\t0\t0\t0\t0\t1512,658\t1515,752\t1518,797\t1521,707\t1524,744\t1527,627\t1530,871\t1534,002\t1537,086\t1540,320\t1543,217\t1546,010\t1548,660\t1551,385\t1554,253\t1557,074\t1560,193\t1563,116\t1566,043\t1568,963\t1571,855\t1574,957\t1577,954\t1581,128\t1584,273\t43\t42\t39\t40\t56\t50\t56\t62\t65\t54\t59\t62\t75\t79\t73\t63\t67\t77\t73\t75\t68\t62\t54\t51\t51\t100 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN'
len_message b'1685'
data b' 2020/03/11\t14:42:05\t318411\t4\t1\t25\t0\t0\t0\t0\t1513,094\t1516,156\t1519,154\t1521,969\t1525,029\t1527,813\t1530,921\t1533,869\t1536,740\t1539,943\t1542,921\t1545,879\t1548,843\t1551,849\t1554,760\t1557,943\t1560,782\t1563,931\t1566,786\t1569,751\t1572,690\t1575,535\t1578,638\t1581,755\t1584,759\t41\t39\t33\t39\t48\t44\t49\t55\t61\t58\t64\t55\t68\t74\t68\t59\t57\t74\t61\t68\t58\t64\t54\t47\t46\t2\t25\t0\t0\t0\t0\t1512,963\t1515,935\t1518,857\t1521,849\t1524,655\t1527,577\t1530,332\t1533,233\t1536,204\t1539,488\t1542,571\t1545,725\t1549,200\t1552,430\t1555,332\t1558,484\t1561,201\t1564,285\t1567,001\t1569,870\t1572,758\t1575,491\t1578,512\t1581,547\t1584,405\t48\t43\t37\t42\t57\t54\t59\t62\t67\t58\t71\t59\t77\t82\t82\t64\t71\t88\t77\t79\t72\t73\t63\t49\t50\t3\t25\t0\t0\t0\t0\t1513,394\t1516,517\t1519,536\t1522,082\t1525,428\t1527,963\t1531,288\t1534,102\t1536,659\t1539,757\t1542,707\t1545,627\t1548,389\t1551,459\t1554,406\t1557,986\t1560,667\t1564,103\t1567,036\t1570,144\t1573,189\t1575,888\t1579,185\t1582,323\t1585,338\t35\t36\t32\t37\t57\t58\t61\t64\t75\t73\t70\t62\t61\t62\t59\t51\t52\t64\t58\t62\t70\t70\t64\t54\t55\t4\t25\t0\t0\t0\t0\t1512,658\t1515,752\t1518,797\t1521,707\t1524,744\t1527,627\t1530,871\t1534,002\t1537,086\t1540,320\t1543,217\t1546,010\t1548,660\t1551,385\t1554,253\t1557,074\t1560,193\t1563,116\t1566,043\t1568,963\t1571,855\t1574,957\t1577,954\t1581,128\t1584,273\t43\t42\t39\t40\t56\t50\t56\t62\t65\t54\t59\t62\t75\t79\t73\t63\t67\t77\t73\t75\t68\t62\t54\t51\t51\t100 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN'
len_message b'1685'
data b' 2020/03/12\t14:42:05\t318411\t4\t1\t25\t0\t0\t0\t0\t1513,094\t1516,156\t1519,154\t1521,969\t1525,029\t1527,813\t1530,921\t1533,869\t1536,740\t1539,943\t1542,921\t1545,879\t1548,843\t1551,849\t1554,760\t1557,943\t1560,782\t1563,931\t1566,786\t1569,751\t1572,690\t1575,535\t1578,638\t1581,755\t1584,759\t41\t39\t33\t39\t48\t44\t49\t55\t61\t58\t64\t55\t68\t74\t68\t59\t57\t74\t61\t68\t58\t64\t54\t47\t46\t2\t25\t0\t0\t0\t0\t1512,963\t1515,935\t1518,857\t1521,849\t1524,655\t1527,577\t1530,332\t1533,233\t1536,204\t1539,488\t1542,571\t1545,725\t1549,200\t1552,430\t1555,332\t1558,484\t1561,201\t1564,285\t1567,001\t1569,870\t1572,758\t1575,491\t1578,512\t1581,547\t1584,405\t48\t43\t37\t42\t57\t54\t59\t62\t67\t58\t71\t59\t77\t82\t82\t64\t71\t88\t77\t79\t72\t73\t63\t49\t50\t3\t25\t0\t0\t0\t0\t1513,394\t1516,517\t1519,536\t1522,082\t1525,428\t1527,963\t1531,288\t1534,102\t1536,659\t1539,757\t1542,707\t1545,627\t1548,389\t1551,459\t1554,406\t1557,986\t1560,667\t1564,103\t1567,036\t1570,144\t1573,189\t1575,888\t1579,185\t1582,323\t1585,338\t35\t36\t32\t37\t57\t58\t61\t64\t75\t73\t70\t62\t61\t62\t59\t51\t52\t64\t58\t62\t70\t70\t64\t54\t55\t4\t25\t0\t0\t0\t0\t1512,658\t1515,752\t1518,797\t1521,707\t1524,744\t1527,627\t1530,871\t1534,002\t1537,086\t1540,320\t1543,217\t1546,010\t1548,660\t1551,385\t1554,253\t1557,074\t1560,193\t1563,116\t1566,043\t1568,963\t1571,855\t1574,957\t1577,954\t1581,128\t1584,273\t43\t42\t39\t40\t56\t50\t56\t62\t65\t54\t59\t62\t75\t79\t73\t63\t67\t77\t73\t75\t68\t62\t54\t51\t51\t100 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN'
len_message b''
out of loop
okay enter *x 32 times*
```

Why is there a gap after 3 data blocks printed on the console? Why is the *'Calculating'* print statement not printed and why is it first executing the first thread (receiving all data blocks) and then performing the calculations of the second thread?

I wanted both to happen simultaneously. I understand that the second thread takes more time but that is why I added the delay in sending the data to make sure by the time 10 data blocks each of 0.0002s are sent + 0.5s delay is added = 0.502s, by then the loop of the second thread should have executed 5 times.

How can I make sure that they are in parallel? Considering my server is going to be a hardware which will continuously send data blocks at a sampling rate of 100Hz and there will be no limit to the data blocks sent.

Comment: Threads in Python don't actually execute concurrently, it's more like cooperative multitasking which is accomplished by them being forced to take turns being executed the interpreter. This is done using something called the GIL (Global Interpreter Lock) — look it up.

Comment: The edit from @martineau was good - some code was given inline code formatting, some para breaks were added for readability, the code formatting blocks were improved, and general pleading material was removed. Technical writing is preferred here. I have rolled back to the improved version.

Comment: @martineau How else can I make them run in parallel? I tried multithreading and ran into this [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62811594/forkingpicklerfile-protocol-dumpobj-typeerror-cannot-pickle-tkinter-tkap]. Could you suggest an alternative for my issue?

Comment: **`multiprocessing`** supports true concurrent processing, but each process runs in its own memory space (unlike `Threads`) which means no sharing of data through globals. A common workaround is to use a `multiprocessing.Queue` to exchange data _or_ one of the objects provided by a `multiprocessing.managers.SyncManager`. However, be aware that the overhead required to share data often severely impacts performance, so much so  that it may cancel-out most or all of the gains from parallel processing.

Comment: Both threads are actually running.  However for each loop in second thread, it takes longer time to process the data than that in first thread.  So when the first thread has put all the data into the queue, the second thread may at that time is processing the second or third data from the queue.  You can try adding `time.sleep(0.1)` in the loop of first thread and see the different.

Comment: @acw1668 Why isn't it working when the server has a `time.sleep(0.5)` after sending 10 data blocks? It should work that way also right? In that 0.5s it should process and write 5 data blocks.

Comment: The sleep in the server after sending 10 blocks does not affect the behavior of the two threads.

Comment: @acw1668 But why not? Sorry, if this question is too silly but I don't understand how that wouldn't affect it. With my understanding the buffer is filled with 10 data blocks out of which the second thread must process 5 of them.

Comment: @martineau When I try using `multiprocessing.Queue` I get `TypeError: cannot pickle 'weakref' object` [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62830911/typeerror-cannot-pickle-weakref-object]. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Since you connect the server before starting the two threads, the server has started sending data to client even the two threads are not started.  Therefore, the sleep in server may not have the effect what you expect.  If you move the line `self.s.connect((self.host, self.port))` into the beginning of `getData()`, you may get what you expect.

Comment: @acw1668 When I try that it gives an error. Instead of receiving 1685 bytes of data, it receives lesser and goes to the thread 1 and receives the remaining and fails because the last byte is `NaN` and so the second also fails. Inside `recvData` after receiving the 4 bytes, it gives `len_message1 b'79  '` which is a part of the first data block.

Comment: I don't have such issue.  Try increasing the receive buffer size and see whether it helps.

Comment: @acw1668 And you say that I connect the server before starting the threads, the server has sending the data to the client, where is the data going? I start receiving only when I click the button on my GUI to call the `getData` function. Shouldn't I be losing some data then? Because, I see even if I click on the button after few minutes, I receive all the data sent by the server.

Comment: @acw1668 My buffer size has to be 4 to receive the length of the data block and then go one to receive so much. So I cannot really increase the buffer size here. Not sure where I am going wrong, since you say it worked for you

Comment: There are cache buffer in the OS level that hold the data.  The server will stop sending data if the client cache buffer is full.  Actually the client application is reading from the cache buffer instead.

Comment: @acw1668 Thank you so much! I tried it again. And it worked. I can see the delay from the server side when I move the `self.s.connect((self.host, self.port))` to `getData()`. Also, thank you so much for clearing all the question I had related to socket programming and multithreading.

Comment: @acw1668 Since you said that the cache buffer in the OS holds the data. Is it not possible for me to have a client that receives data after after a certain gap in time to receive the data streamed by the server at that instance? For eg. if the server sends data1-data10 in a total of 10s. Is it possible to implement the client to receive at an interval of 2s and therefore receive only data2, data4, data6, data8 and data10?

Comment: No you can't because the cache buffer will still hold the unread data even though the client application sleeps for certain period.  You need to discard the data manually after reading.

Comment: Only objects that can be pickled can be put into a `multiprocessing.Queue` — so it sounds like you're trying to put something into one that cannot be.

Answer (score 0):

Threads run almost simultaneously. with threads, as soon as one starts the next thread starts. therefore there is a slight delay from the 1st to the 2nd.. etc if you're after real simultaneous processing you need to use your cores instead.

Comment: I am okay with slight delay but it seems to me that the second thread stops in between and waits for the first thread to finish before it continues. I would want to avoid that because my hardware will not stop to send data blacks. It continuously streams it. And could you explain what you mean when you say use your cores instead?